# Magento 2 How to Remove Particular Product Price in Category Page?

Tags: magento2, product, category, price

I want remove particular product price in category page.

Comment: There is not enough actionable information here to offer an answer. Can you edit your question to include: (0) You want to show/remove the price for the specific type of product.  (1) Do you want to remove the price for Out of stock products? (2) You want to remove the price for a specific product only. With this, it may be possible to offer an answer …

Comment: I want to show/remove the price for the specific type of product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an attribute of Yes/No type with the name is_hide_price.

then assign attribute value to particular product

app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Replace:

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

to

```
<?php
if ($_product->getIsHidePrice() == 1) {
    echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product);
}?>
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `list.phtml` template file.

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Search for the below price code, from where your price is displayed.

Replace:
`<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>`

To:

```
<?php
$productType = 'configurable'; // add your product type here for which you want to remove the price i.e. configurable, simple, grouped, virtual, downloadable and bundle.
if ($_product->getTypeId() != $productType) {
    echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_product);
}
?>
```

This will not show the prices for products with type **configurable** from your list pages.

Hope this will help!